# How to add background to pdf and save as image in python

Tags: python, image, pdf, export

I want to add a background to multiple pdfs and save the documents as images e.g. jpg

I use PyPDF2 and the code below to add the background and save as pdf, which works fine, but I need the files to be saved as jpg. So currently I could make a 2 stage process

1) add background and save as pdf

2) open pdf and export to jpg using e.g. pdf2image

But this woudl be inefficient as it requires redundant save/read operations. So the question is how to perform both operations of adding background and saving as jpg without the middle step of saving as pdf? Is there an easy way to pass a writer object directly to pdf2image? Or perhaps there is a simpler way of doing this.

```
for folderName, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(SourceFolder):
    for x in filenames:
        if x.endswith(".pdf"):
            with open(os.path.join(SourceFolder, x), "rb") as overlay, open(bckround.pdf, "rb") as  inFile:
                original = pypdf.PdfFileReader(inFile)
                background = original.getPage(0)
                foreground = pypdf.PdfFileReader(overlay).getPage(0)

                # merge the first two pages
                background.mergePage(foreground)

                # add all pages to a writer
                writer = pypdf.PdfFileWriter()
                for i in range(original.getNumPages()):
                    page = original.getPage(i)
                    writer.addPage(page)

                #write everything in the writer to a file
                with open(os.path.join(targetDirectory, x), "wb") as outFile:
                   writer.write(outFile)
```